# uname -m -p -i. What does every parameter stand for?

Tags: utilities, x86, architecture

I have CentOS7 installed on my computer. `uname -a` prints the following:

```
Linux c7 3.10.0-1127.el7.centos.plus.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 5 18:08:31 UTC 2020 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

As stated in `man uname` page, `uname -m` denotes *machine hardware name* (i686 in my case), `uname -p` denotes *processor type* (i686 in my case) and `uname -i` denotes *hardware platform* (i386 in my case). I have been trying to find out what exactly every option means. After hours of searching I came to the conclusion that there are contradictions among given answers (even on StackExchange). As far as I understand, `uname -m` stands for what architecture the kernel was compiled for, therefore, in my case I have a Linux kernel which is build for i686 ISA (**right?**). But I have some misunderstanding about `uname -p`. People (and some docs) claim that it prints the ISA of the processor. I have i7-4800MQ, so `uname -p` should print something like x86_x64/amd64/x86-x64, but it prints i686. I think that it might be due to the reason that my CPU works in Legacy Mode (or so) using i686 ISA, since the distro is 32-bit (**right?**). The last option is `uname -i` which prints i386. I don't even have any assumptions about this one. I don't see any connection with i386 architecture in these conditions. Can someone clearly explain what does every parameter stand for in my case?

Comment: In the question linked above, read the Fedora part — CentOS is a derivative of Fedora.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, it does answer my question. You're my savior. Thanks a lot!